# All links in markdown editing help should open in a new window

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, editor

In the markdown editing help there are two links that go else where - the Advanced help link and the link about what HTML is supported. The HTML link does not open in a new window, like the advanced help one does.

Would just be more usable if it opened in a new window too.

[image: Showing which links we're talking about.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed; for consistency, the behavior should be identical. Done in the next build.